# Python - find max value

Tags: python

Sort of new and learning Python but I think this is a simple one but I'm having trouble with. I need to find the average of 5 numbers for each row in a column, which I've done and confirmed by going into the csv in excel and checking my numbers. Now I need to return just the max value. I've tried a few things but can't seem to get it working. Not allowed to use 3rd party packages like Pandas, etc.

Here's my code:

```
def no_avg(in_file):
    with open(in_file, newline='', encoding='utf-16') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter='|')
        next(data, None)
        rows = [row for row in data]
        for row in rows:
            num_avg = ((float(row[6]) + float(row[7]) + float(row[8]) + float(row[9]) + float(row[10])) / 5)
            print(row[0],num_avg)
```

It prints out the first column and the calculated average for each row, but when I try to use max() on num_avg to just get the highest value, I get 'Float is not iterable' as the error and I'm not 100% sure on how to correct that.

Comment: You want `max(row, key=float)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `max` of the row (I assume cells 6-10, the same ones you were taking the average of), you need to take the max of those original numbers; it's not possible to get the max from the computed average.

```
import csv

def no_max(in_file):
    with open(in_file, newline='', encoding='utf-16') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter='|')
        next(data, None)  # skip header
        for row in data:
            print(row[0], max(row[6:11], key=float))
```